# How does the ndk know to include .y files

Tags: android-ndk

I hope this question even makes sense.

I'm trying to link an executable of 3 .c files using the android ndk make enviroment.

Some of the .c files have files with the same name except they have a .y extension (for yacc/bison example: file.c and file.y).  My question is how does the ndk know when to include these .y files in the linking process.  I don't have them anywhere in the android.mk.  Also I have noticed that the ndk still looks for the .y file when I remove it from the directory.

Thanks

edit:  any information you have about anything related to how the ndk works is also welcome.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, I know that the `make` utility has built in knowledge of common build processes. If it recognizes certain patterns, it can know to expect other related files. I am assuming something similar is happening under the hood with the ndk, and I would like to see a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks Mr Shickadance. I'm actually using the x86 project's ndk but I figured the two are similar enough thatIf I could get an understanding for one then the other would be easier to understand.

Comment: The NDK makefiles and toolchains have no reference to .y files or yacc/bison. Is it possible that your c files are #including the y files?